# Continue the loop after an exception used in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to run a loop with try and exception in python. Initially it runs for p=0 and j=1,2 then falls into the exception. the problem is that then I would like the loop to continue for p=1 and j=1,2,2....can you help me thanks! I tried something like this but it's not working

```
for p in range(1):
    for j in range(23):
     try:

      b = response_json[0]['countries'][p]['names'][j]['values']
     except:
         break
```

Comment: To cite the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare `except:` clause. [...] A bare `except:` clause will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, using exceptions to handle normal flow is a bad pattern. Exceptions are for, well, exceptions.

Looks like you are trying to iterate over an array with missing keys. Instead of trying each key, you could iterate over the collection directly

```
country_data = response_json[0]['countries']

for country in country_data:
   for name in country['names']:
      b = name['values']
```

Comment: A ok thanks a lot, it's working!! sorry beginner

Answer (score 0):

Replace `break` with `continue` (or `pass`).

`break` jumps to the end of the loop, `continue` jumps back to the start to continue with the next iteration. `pass` is a no-op used when a block is empty.